# Can you use setfill() to set fill 2 digits?

Tags: c++, date, formatting, ostream, iomanip

Say if I want to display 2018 when the input is 18, how can I make it display the "20" in 2018? I tried using setfill("20") and it won't work as it's a string rather than a char. But when I used setfill('2'); it will display 2218.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way to do this. You can just write a function which will check the length of string representation of a number and append a "20" prefix if needed.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be `std::cout << "20" << whatever_variable_holds_18 << '\n';`

Answer (score 0):

The formatting facility [`setfill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) is designed to fill the empty space by repeating one single char.  So it is not possible to obtain this effect, using a string.

For time formatting, you'd have the possibility to use [`put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) with a formatting string to indicate the desired format (e.g. `Y` for `2018` and `y` for `18`), provided you have a real date (so year 2018) passed in a [`tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) structure.

In your case,  you could try something like:

```
cout << (year<100 ? year:year+2000);
```

But a better approach would be to either ensure that the date is entered on 4 digits (this will avoid you the future bug of the year 2100), or use some function for doing that, so that --if needed-- your future you could easily find the delicate places in your code.